# Adding a new item in dictionary from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency

I have a problem adding a new item to a Static dictionary while using it from multiple threads. Any ideas where I'm doing it wrong?
Initializing the dictionary:

```
public static class Server
{
    public static volatile Dictionary<int, List<SomeClass>> Values;
}
```

Trying to add an item:

```
Server.Values.Add(someInt, new List<SomeClass> { elements});
```

Comment: Yes, you're using a type which is documented as not being thread safe, from multiple threads without anything to make that safe.

Comment: I think I could probably guess, but why don't you tell us what the problem is rather than making us guess?

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: thats the problem - studio doesnt give a error - it just breaks

Comment: Define "breaks"

Comment: When you say "breaks", developers think of a very specific thing, though again I'm guessing that's not what you meant.

Comment: starts from the start of the method without adding anything - endless cicle

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As explained by Jon Skeet you are using an object  which is not guaranteed to be thread safe

try using  [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) which is designed for Concurrency Scenario With  Many threads

```
public static class Server
{
    public static  ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<SomeClass>> Values =
                      new ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<SomeClass>>(); 
}
```

Here how to use it

```
bool added = Server.Values.TryAdd(someInt, new List<SomeClass> { elements});
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter  Well done to mention it  I forgot  to  add it. It was a time constraint

Comment: in this case added = false and Server.Values = null. Thats the most of "error" i get

Comment: you  have to initiliaze it first I  updated my answer

Answer (score 7):

In general, when working with resources that are shared between multiple threads, you need to use a synchronization mechanism, like `lock()` to make your code thread safe.  Create a common object to use as the lock:

```
private object _lock = new object();
```

Then you surround any code which accesses your shared resource, like this:

```
lock(_lock)
{
    // perform operations on shared resource here.
}
```

It's important to note that you should have *a different lock for every shared resource* rather than one lock used for all resources.  If you use your lock object with multiple resources, your code could be very inefficient.  If one thread grabs the lock so it can use resource A, then other threads will have to wait for the lock to be released even if they want to access resource B which has nothing to do with the resource A.  Therefore, it's better to have one lock object per resource and to name your lock objects so you know which resources they should be used with.

An alternative to this (as BRAHIM Kamel's answer shows) is to use a replacement, if available, for your shared resource which already has thread synchronization baked in, like `ConcurrentDictionary`.  Though this may not be feasible in your case.

Comment: why reinvinting the weel if you have  concurrentDictionary :p

Comment: this is worth to be mentioned in case he can't change the type +1

Comment: I'd prefer a variable `ServerDictionaryLock`, then it's clear what you are locking with it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter -- well, I've tried to make it as generic as possible, but I see your point.

Comment: @rory.ap: the problem with the `_lock` object is that people implement it in that way and it suggests to use one lock-variable per class. That will lock the whole instance and on any action that uses it.

Comment: ...which can lead to deadlocks.  Of course.  Okay I'll update. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @rory.ap: not deadlocks but it would be inefficient to lock the whole instance if you only need to lock  part of it. Deadlocks can only occur if you have multiple (nested) locks and each lock needs resources that the other has but the other has to wait for you too.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I just arrived at that conclusion as well.